# How to find dates of specific day of current month in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar), and I want to highlight dates day wise as am getting Wednesday from server and i want to highlight all Wednesday to be selected on `FSCalendar` of current month or year. Please solve this. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

`FSCalendar` has a delegate for cases like this, it's called *titleDefaultColorForDate* and you can use it this way:

```
func calendar(calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, titleDefaultColorForDate date: NSDate) -> UIColor? {
    return calendar.gregorian.component(.Weekday, fromDate: date) == 4 ? UIColor.blueColor() : UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

Let me elaborate: What this delegate method does is return a `UIColor` based on the *date* that's passed by reference when the view loads, in other words, every time a month loads this method is called 30+ times with every single date in it. Here i made the condition to return true if the given date was equal to `4` since that's how *Wednesday* is represented by this helper

```
calendar.gregorian.component(.Weekday, fromDate: date)  // calendar is my FSCalendar outlet.
```

To summarize, *Wednesday* are blue and every other week day is black.

**PS:** Notice *Wednesday* = 4 in my case since my week begins on *Sunday*, otherwise you must do this calculation based on your starting day.